# How can I test the permission of a file right in java?

Tags: java, file, permissions

I am writing a file explorer.
It works just fine actually. But when I try to open specific files, I get an error. When I type in the path of those files in the file explorer of windows, I don't have accesses to them, so I am guessing that this is the reason for the error.
No I dont want to show those files in the file explorer of mine.

I tested the following:

```
 File F = new File(path);
    Path P = Paths.get(path);
    if(Files.isWritable(P)==true){
        //do stuff
    }
```

and

```
 File F = new File(path);
    Path P = Paths.get(path);
    if(Files.isExecutable(P)==true){
        //do stuff
    }
```

Instead of `isWriteable` I also tried:

```
 F.canWrite();
```

and

```
 F.canRead();
```

Unfortunaly it always returns true, even though I cannot accesses the files.
What is also puzzling me is that the error is the following one:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at inst.FilesChange.ShowFiles(FilesChange.java:29)
at inst.FilesChange.NextFiles(FilesChange.java:54)
at inst.JFD3Installer$5.mouseClicked(JFD3Installer.java:127)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
```

But the list of files :

```
  File L[] = F.listFiles();
```

is not empty or anything, but I can the error at

```
L.lenght();
```

This does not work either:

```
 if(L.length>0){
     /do stuff
  }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you making a difference between files and directories? A directory can be readable, but it does not mean that all the files in the directory are readable. Also you should read the warning associated with [`Files.isReadable(path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isReadable-java.nio.file.Path-)

Comment: Yes. The user is just supposed to open dirs. He is not able to choose files on the explorer. I read the warning, but it did not say security in the thrown error.

Comment: java.io.File is an obsolete class.  I recommend you avoid it completely, and only use Path/Paths/Files.  The File.listFiles method will return null, with no further explanation, if an error occurs, but methods like [Files.newDirectoryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream(java.nio.file.Path)) and [Files.list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#list(java.nio.file.Path)) will throw an informative exception if they fail.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, forgot to mention though, that F.listFiles(); does not throw the error, but when I request the length of L with L.length it does, Thanks for the recommendation anyway, I will try it with it for now, maybe it will work better.